# Merge almost duplicate rows based on some columns criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, aggregate

I have a pandas dataframe with several rows that are near duplicates of each other, except for one value. My goal is to merge these rows into a single row, without summing the numerical values.

Here is an example of what I'm working with:

| Name | Text | Value1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Ab | 2 |
| A | Abc | 0 |
| A | Abcd | 2 |
| B | A | 0 |
| B | Ab | 2 |

I would like a new dataframe with the unique "Name" (name column), but containing the following information:

- the concatenation of the "Value1" column
- Criteria1: the number of values from Value1_concat that are equal to 2
- Text_Criteria1: the texts that respect Criteria1 (texts with Value1 == 2)
- Total: total number of values from Value1_concat list (meaning 3 for A, 2 for B)

| Name | Value1_concat | Criteria1 | Text_Criteria1 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | [2,0,2] | 2 | "Ab. Abcd" | 3 |
| B | [0,2] | 1 | "Ab." | 2 |

What would be the best way to tackle this issue? I've looked into the groupby() function but I still don't understand it very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using pandas `groupby()` function in combination with custom aggregation functions. Here's a possible solution to your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {'Name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
        'Text': ['Ab', 'Abc', 'Abcd', 'A', 'Ab'],
        'Value1': [2, 0, 2, 0, 2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Custom aggregation functions
def concat_values(series):
    return list(series)

def count_criteria1(series):
    return sum(value == 2 for value in series)

def text_criteria1(series, value_series):
    return ". ".join(text for text, value in zip(series, value_series) if value == 2)

def total(series):
    return len(series)

# Group by 'Name' and apply custom aggregation functions
result = df.groupby('Name').agg({
    'Value1': [concat_values, count_criteria1, total],
    'Text': lambda x: text_criteria1(x, df.loc[x.index, 'Value1'])
}).reset_index()

# Rename columns
result.columns = ['Name', 'Value1_concat', 'Criteria1', 'Total', 'Text_Criteria1']

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a separate groupby call to get the criteria information.

all rows:

```
df.groupby("Name").agg(
   Value1_concat = ("Value1", list),
   Total = ("Value1", len)
)
```

```
     Value1_concat  Total
Name                     
A        [2, 0, 2]      3
B           [0, 2]      2
```

criteria rows:

```
df[ df["Value1"] == 2 ].groupby("Name").agg(
   Criteria1 = ("Text", len),
   Text_Criteria1 = ("Text", ". ".join),
)
```

```
      Criteria1 Text_Criteria1
Name                          
A             2       Ab. Abcd
B             1             Ab
```

You can `.join` them together:

```
(df
 .groupby("Name").agg(
    Value1_concat = ("Value1", list),
    Total = ("Value1", len))
 .join(
    df[ df["Value1"] == 2 ].groupby("Name").agg(
       Criteria1 = ("Text", len),
       Text_Criteria1 = ("Text", ". ".join)))
)
```

```
     Value1_concat  Total  Criteria1 Text_Criteria1
Name                                               
A        [2, 0, 2]      3          2       Ab. Abcd
B           [0, 2]      2          1             Ab
```